# SQL Delete Syntax Error, also some PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a database table named 'favoritecats' with the following fields:

- id
- catName
- catId

I am using Jquery to run this function on click event of an  element on DOM Ready.

```
// Delete a Favorite Category from SQL Database
    $('.deleteCatFavs').click(function(){      // On click of .deleteCatFavs
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_delFavCat";    // My Personal PHP Controller Identifier
    var url = "index.php";                     // URL to post to

// Now Im getting the data I want to post into variables.
    var catId = $("input[name=FavCats]:checked").val();
    var rowId = $("input[name=FavCats]:checked").attr("id");

// Now we make the post
    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, rowId: rowId},
        function(data){
            $("#favCats").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    });
```

**This all Works Fine,**

**But below** I have the PHP Code to delete the selected rowId from above from the database.
Here is where im having the issue, Im sure its a SQL error.

```
public function AJAX_delFavCat(){

$rowId = isset($_POST['rowId'])?$_POST['rowId']:''; // Get Posted Variable
// Below, I want to delete the posted rowId, from the DB,
$this->database->query("DELETE FROM 'favoritecats' WHERE id='$rowId'");

// My personal Loaders, I need help with the delete query above!!
$data = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM favoritecats");
$this->load->view('Ajax_addToFavCats.php', $data, $ajax=1);

} // End
```

**The "DELETE FROM 'favoritecats' WHERE id='$rowId'" doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?**

**[EDIT]**
I get the following error through SQL:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''favoritecats' WHERE id='27'' at line 1

Also, How would I write a Jquery function using the $.ajax method instead of the $.post method im using now, does it really make a difference?

Comment: As far as I know, $.post is just a shorthand $.ajax function.

Comment: Try to do a var_dump($rowId) of your $rowId to check if you have the correct ID before doing the query.

Comment: Hi, Yes It picks up the correct string in Jquery, and PHP, I tested both, Im sure its the delete SQL statement, I get the following error.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''favoritecats' WHERE id='27'' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **what am I doing wrong?**

You've got a SQL-injection security hole.
See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Change this

```
$rowId = isset($_POST['rowId'])?$_POST['rowId']:''; // Get Posted Variable
// Below, I want to delete the posted rowId, from the DB,
$this->database->query("DELETE FROM 'favoritecats' WHERE id='$rowId'");
```

To this

```
$rowId = isset($_POST['rowId'])?$_POST['rowId']:''; // Get Posted Variable
$rowId = mysql_real_escape_string($rowId);
// Below, I want to delete the posted rowId, from the DB,
$this->database->query("DELETE FROM `favoritecats` WHERE id='$rowId'");
```

To properly escape your inputs.

**Back to your question**

```
$this->database->query("DELETE FROM `favoritecats` WHERE id='$rowId'");
```

Will fix your error.
Note the use of backticks around tablenames, Normal quotes are not allowed and are in fact a `syntax error`.

Comment: @PHP_Guy, I think it's best to ask that in a new question, otherwise everything will get messed up here :-).

Comment: quick update: I had to use $('foo')live("click", function(){}, just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Table name should not be in single quotes. Use backticks or leave it as it is .

```
DELETE FROM 'favoritecats' - wrong
DELETE FROM `favoritecats` - correct
DELETE FROM favoritecats - also correct
```